# R and LaTeX: Why does white-space character disappear from path?

Tags: errors, pdftex, r, paths

I'm creating a manual for an R package using LaTeX, and I have to follow a [specific latex style](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/BiocStyle/inst/doc/LatexStyle2.pdf) . So, I want to create PDF using well known pdflatex, starting form `.tex` file generated by *'knitr'*. 
Every time I launched pdflatex, I got the same error:

```
LaTeX errors:
! LaTeX Error: File `C:/ProgramFiles/R/R-3.3.2/library/BiocStyle/resources/tex/Bioconductor2.sty' not found.
```

And it always fails in this line of .tex:

```
\RequirePackage{C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.2/library/BiocStyle/resources/tex/Bioconductor2}
```

Of course the file exists and it is in that folder.

I tried using both native R code, and TeX live or MikTek 2.9 (on Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines): always the same error. It seems that it cannot find `Bioconductor2.sty` because of the path to the file: see `C:/ProgramFiles/...` (in error message!) instead of `C:/Program Files/...` (in `.tex` file).

Why it happens? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: spaces are removed from that argument, so you can use `\RequirePackage{pkg1 , pkg2 }` but just as you do not use `\documentclass{/usr/local/tex/whatever/article}` you should not use a path in RequirePackage.  Just use `\RequirePackage{Bioconductor2}` and ensure externally that that is in the tex path